# QT Cannot include file QtWebKitWidgets : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, webview, qt5.5

In .pro file I have the line:

```
QT += core gui webkitwidgets
```

and:

```
#include <QtWebKitWidgets>
```

But I get:

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWebKitWidgets': No such file or directory
```

Answers to similar questions on Stackoverflow did not help. How to solve this problem?

OS: Windows 8.1

Qt version: 5.5.1

Comment: Please add the #include line to your question

Comment: Have you tried to rerun qmake?

Comment: @MrEricSir ok. I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The matter turned out that I used in the assembly Qt version 5.4.2 instead of 5.5.1.